# Is my plan for wiring lights and outlets correct?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle

Could someone take a look at this wiring plan and let me know if this looks ok? I've done basic wiring in the past, but never had occasion to use 12/3 wiring before. Something about having two hot wires and a single neutral is giving me pause.

[image: wiring plan]

Comment: Reuben, what software did you use to generate your wire diagram?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Wouldn't be surprised if it is Visio with the pencil/marker tool to draw the lines by hand.

Comment: Rule of thumb is to keep your outlets separate (on a separate breaker) from your lighting.

Comment: The switch only needs a 12/2 if it's a single-pole. If it's a smart-switch then you need the neutral I believe.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket made it in Microsoft Powerpoint

Answer (score 11):

Looks legit, though if you haven't priced the 12/3 yet, you may wish for a way to do it all with a bigger spool of 12/2.  (take power to the switch, hop from outlet to outlet, have the  lights be a spur).

**Note that the ceiling junction boxes need to be *enormous***. The center box will have *10* conductors + 4 grounds (4 for the price of 1 = *1 wire* count) + *2* for the lamp pigtails + *1* for cable clamps.  So that's 14, x 2.25" = **31.5 cubic inches**.  That's far larger than a typical round or octagon box.

Your best bet is probably a 4-11/16 (120mm) metal box, (42 cubic inches), or 4"x 2-1/8" metal box (30 ci) plus a "mud ring" giving a 4" round opening (3-4 ci).  I'm not aware of any round boxes in plastic-land that will have that many cubic inches.

Also this wiring is very "wire heavy" due to the *circuity* (word for "indirect route"; not an electrical term) of coming down from the ceiling rose for each receptacle.  For wire conservation reasons, *and also* diversity of circuit reasons, I prefer running 1 cable down a wall and serving outlets on both sides of the wall. This means any given room has access to 2-4 circuits, and this is a very good thing when you have a home office or gaming-PC room with a lot of gear that is tripping 1 circuit.

Comment: Are connectors for cables really that big in (I assume) the US? My electrician connected 2 or 3 times as many cables in a standard ceiling box here in Denmark. Almost all these wires would be connected using a simple lamp outlet. I use these ones: "Lampeudtag Universal WEXØE Ø80 hvid". It would only need one extra connection because it can only accept 2 switched hot wires

Comment: @Orbit: the US NEC has rules stating how full a box can be. 1 cubic inch for the connectors isn't their actual size but their allotment for space. The rules are such that you don't have a box that is absolutely jam-packed.

Comment: @whatsisname: Thanks, that makes sense. My box is definitely jam-packed, not that easy to work with. It is an old house though, probably they would also do it differently now.

Comment: 32cu in. is the standard two-gang box size, no? Doesn't seem particularly enormous to me. Also, you could use 'circuitousness' as a synonym for 'circuity' if you like.

Comment: @TylerH Light fixtures don't go in gang boxes, they use octagon boxes, and those are 21.5 cu.in. at the largest.  Normally you try to plan the routing to not end up with huge intersections in ceiling boxes because there's only so much room in those boxes and the alternative is to hack something like Harper's talking about (ie: a big square box with a mud ring to provide the required mounting points for the fixture).

Comment: @J... we're talking about a junction box, not a fixture box.

Comment: @TylerH But... lights go onto fixture boxes so we *are* talking about them because that's what OP is proposing.  You said 32cu.in doesn't seem enormous but it's 50% larger than the largest octagon box you can get, so in the context of ceiling boxes it **is** enormous.

Comment: @J... It was my understanding from the img that  the light has its own housing and is simply connected to the junction box. So I guess its just a little misleading/confusing in the answer to call it a "junction box"... it's really a ceiling mount. A "*junction*" box to me is usually "whatever extra box you have lying around that is big enough" (unless we are talking something for a conduit run, which this doesn't seem to be), AKA standard receptacle boxes. 32cu is not enormous for that, given that's a common size for 2-gang receps, as I mentioned above.

Comment: @JBTW ceiling lights often get mounted in round boxes, or even square, not just octagonal ones (in fact I have seen far more round than octagonal, but I guess YMMV). The fact it seems enormous to you may just be because you are not thinking about other shapes of boxes, which commonly do come in much larger sizes.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, when I say "octagon" box I mean octos or rounds of the same trade size.  The biggest is still 21.5 cu.in.  And yes, OP's picture is a bit confusing.  The blue circles I think are meant to be the light fixtures and the "junction box" shown is meant to be the device box (ie: a ceiling box).  Otherwise you'd need an access panel on the ceiling for each junction beside the octo.  And yes, enormous because it means not using a standard ceiling box but instead requires using a huge square junction in there with a mud ring instead.

Comment: @TylerH all boxes must remain accessible without disassembling the building. So using a 2-gang box for those splices means a 2-gang blank cover on the ceiling Like I say if you really wanted to do that, 4-11/16 + round mud ring.  You may be thinking of "down lights" where they provide their own special J-box up in the hole, that is UL approved for the downlight string **only**.  Those boxes are not approved for any other wires, and sticking 2-gang J-boxes accessible only through down-light holes violates the above rule.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I was thinking you'd just go into the attic to to access the junction box which has a normal plate/cover on it. We don't have any info from OP about such relevant details that might require such special circumstances (e.g. this being a ceiling with another floor/storey above it or a ceiling with no attic space above it), so I assume the most common situation: there's a ceiling and there's an accessible attic space above it.

Answer (score 6):

Totally normal. We might call the red wire a "switched hot" because yes, it does provide a line/hot connection, but it is different from an ordinary continuous line/hot wire because it can be interrupted or switched.

With this topology the /3 connection is required for the switch loop because code requires neutral to be present at switch locations (years ago this was not required).

The /3 connection between the light fixtures is for convenience and cost savings. A person could have used two /2 cables (one for the always-on receptacles and one for the switched lights) but this duplicates the neutral unnecessarily and creates confusion (correct pairing of neutrals and hots, and distinguishing the switched light-hot from the always-on hot for the receptacles).

Comment: Using two /2 cables would also make box fill even more of a nightmare than it is already.

Answer (score 2):

Would work (provided the box fill requirements are met), but generally it is considered bad form to have unnecessary splices in hard to find or reach locations.

And 50' of 12/3 is going to cost currently about $130, 50' of 12/2 is $80, 250' of 12/2 is $155.

Buy the 250' roll of 12/2, hit the switch with the homerun, then leave the switch box with unswitched hot daisy chaining the receptacles, and another 12/2 to the lights.

You make the splices only where they need to be, only one box needs significant box fill considerations, less work on ladder, and you probably have wire left over.

Answer (score -2):

Based on wire coloring it is probably not European installation (USA maybe?) so I am not sure what local standards and codes are.
Here this would be two circuits one for outlets (breaker -> outlet1 -> outlet2 -> outlet3 -> outlet4) and one for the ligts (breaker -> switch -> light1 -> light2 -> light3).
Outlet circuit would be 2,5mm²(~13awg) and light circuit would be 1,5mm² (~15awg), given the lower voltage comparable wire sizes would be 12awg for lights and 10awg for outlets.
Separating lights from outlets has (besides different wire thickness) a very practical effect - if an appliance trips a breaker, you can still have light and if there is problem with lights you can still use a lamp from an outlet so you are unlikely to go completely dark.